# PHP statements with <<<EOF string

Tags: php, string, if-statement, eof

I have two nested statements inside the construction of a string with `<<<EOF`
After the statements I get an error that I don't understand when continuing adding to the string.

The error is `unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING`

```
function foo_bar() {
    $phrase = "hello world";
    $string = "";

    if (0 == 0) {
        $string .= <<<EOF
        <b>{$phrase}</b>
EOF;
        if (0 == 0) {
            $string .= <<<EOF
            <i> of mine</i>
EOF;
        }
        /* comment out to see the error
        $string .= <<<EOF
        <u> - the END</u>
EOF;
*/
    }

    return $string;
}
add_shortcode('foobar', 'foo_bar');
```

Comment: On which line do you get this error? Please mark it with a comment in the code in your question

Comment: I get "hello world of mine - the END" when I run this.

Comment: We could discuss whether parse errors are on-topic here but your code [doesn't even trigger one](http://3v4l.org/o24eK).

Comment: you are never calling you function  `function foo_bar() `, at-least i am unable to see that calling code. So please provide full code.because it' s working without error if we write `foo_bar()` instead of `add_shortcode('foobar', 'foo_bar');`

Comment: Check if you have a trailing space after `EOF`.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either and I can't tell why: http://codepad.org/DIKrVH4Q.

Comment: Please read my comment carefully. thanks. 
 
you are never calling you function function `foo_bar()` , at-least i am unable to see that calling code. So please provide full code.because it' s working without error if we write `foo_bar()` instead of `add_shortcode('foobar', 'foo_bar');`

Comment: I marked the line where I get the error.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh: Since this question is about a *syntax* error, it is irrelevant whether the function is called or not.

Comment: @FelixKling i found why your code is not working in codepad. You have trailing spaces/tabs in line 19.

Comment: Actually it's working at my end when i do what i said,if i go with that what he given in code. then blank page is come. that's why i am telling that comment.

Comment: I have something working now... I replaced the last `EOF` with `UFO` and it works?? I remember you can use whatever. How is this possible?

Comment: @Rash: Good catch! Then that's likely the issue then, since it would explain the `unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE` part (IMO). This is a verbatim copy of the OP's original code before they added the comment.

Comment: Geeee,  user3584460 was right! is was a trailing space!! Sorry guys, have a nice evening, cheers.

Comment: @FFish: You seem to have  fixed the issue inadvertently when you added the comment around the code block.

Answer (score 0):

So the gist of the discussion in the comments above.

Check for trailing spaces after `EOF;`